# Trying to solve for the largest prime factor without recursion - Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, if-statement

I came across a website called Project Euler and everything was going well until I hit the 3rd problem - The Largest Prime Factor.  I don't want to use recursion to solve it.  I saw solutions online where they use Math.sqrt and I don't want to use that either.  Stubborn, I know.

I'd like to solve it with just loops and if statements.  I assumed the input is an odd number. Here is my code. The output keeps coming out as [3] if num = 99 and I can't figure out why.  I tried putting a puts statement everywhere to see what was being outputted at each step.  One issue I realized was that that the array#p was not resetting after each loop.  I tried array.clear but that wasn't much help.  Could someone point me in the right direction?  Is there some fundamental aspect about arrays, loops, and if-statements that I'm not getting?

```
def prime(num)
    arr = []
    p = []
    not_p = []
    # first I find all the numbers that num is divisible by
    for i in (2..num/2) 
        if num % i == 0
             arr << i
        end
    end # this should output [3, 9, 11, 33]

    arr.each do |x| #  I loop through each element in the above array
        for i in (2..(x/2)) # I divide each element - x -  by 2 because it cannot be divisble by anything greater than its half
            if x % i == 0 # if x is divisble by i
                not_p << i # I push the i into array#not_p
            end # keep looping until i reaches x/2
        end
        if not_p.length == 0 # if there are no values in array#not_p, then I know x is a prime factor
            p << x # so I push x into array#p
        end  
    end
    return p[-1] # returns the last element of the array, which is the largest
end

puts prime(99)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you the full answer, as that would defeat the object of the practice with Project Euler.

However, you're almost on the right track with sorting out your problem. You don't want to look at the array `p` not being emptied, that should be collecting your primes. You do want to look at `not_p` though, since that is the array of divisors of each of your factors.

I hope this helps. Let me know if I can help any more.

Comment: I still need a bit more help.  In the array [3, 9, 11, 33] which 99 is all divisible by, if an element is not divisible by any number up to half the value of the element (so for 9, any number from 2~4) I push that element into array#p.  If it has divisors, I push the divisors into not_p.  Since 9 does have divisors, array#not_p isn't empty therefore 9 is not pushed into array#p.  That is the logic behind my code but it is not working.  What exactly is it about my code that is not doing the exact thing I want it to do?

Comment: That is correct, but your problem lies in that after you first detect a non prime number your `not_p` array has items in. So, each time you come round the loop again `not_p.length` won't be zero ever again, unless you do something about it.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks for the suggestion and I added my solution to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok!  Thanks for the suggestion philnash!  In fact, I knew about that problem and tried to clear the array with Array.clear but that did not work.  Instead, I just moved not_p = [] below the iteration arr.each do |x| and it worked!  It makes sense because the not_p resets to [] when it moves on to the next element.  Thanks so much for your help and for not providing the answer first!  Here is my final, working solution =D

```
def prime(num)
    arr = []
    p = []

    for i in (2..num / 2)   
        if num % i == 0
             arr << i
        end
    end # this should output [3, 9, 11, 33]

    arr.each do |x| 
        not_p = []
        for i in (2..(x / 2)) 
            if x % i == 0 
                not_p << i 
            end 
        end
        if not_p.length == 0 
            p << x 
        end
    end
    return p[-1] 
 end

puts prime(99) # => 29
```